# Centered div over two other divs with auto height

Tags: html, css, css-position

the best way to describe what I'm trying to acomplish will be by showing you this photo:
[image]

As you can see here what I want is a centered div with two divs inside it, and two other divs under div with id content. I need this layout because div left and side will have the same background (other than rest of the page). I managed to do it by using absolute position on div content, however if I do that I don't know how to automatically adjust div left and right height to div content height. Here's how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/95gbd8z5/ and here's the code

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="side"></div>
        <div id="main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum         has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer         took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not         only five centuries</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AND CSS

```
    #container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#left{
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    background: #363837;
}
#right{
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
#content{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 400px;
}
#side{
    height: inherit;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float:left;
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    }
#main{
    background: white;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    }
```

Don't know why in jsfiddle side div height is not the same height as main while using height: auto; it works on my machine on both chrome and IE, but don't bother that, **the main question is, how to adjust height of div left and right to div content height?**

**EDIT: Can't use anything except pure HTML+CSS**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want height of `#left` and `#right` to be the same as `#content` height?

Comment: Yes inside content I have also the main div and there will be the real content of the page, but there's no problem with adjusting content div height as main div is inside it the problem is with left and right

Comment: What do you think about this js solution http://jsfiddle.net/95gbd8z5/3/?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that it can't use anything except HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that the "right" and "left" will take the same height from "container" you can just set "height" to `100%`. In the example I center the content using `transform` property, because if I understand you correct, you want to center the content too.

```css
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding:20px 0;
}

#left {
    width: 50%;
 background: #363837;  
    height:100%; /* that's the key */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#right{
    background: red;
 width: 50%;
 height:100%; /* that's the key */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

#content {
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

#side {
  display:table-cell;
  background:green;
}

#main {
  display:table-cell;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="side">side</div>
    <div id="main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't know why but on my real project this solution is not working, but i will start from the beginning and use yours snippet, can you jest tell me how to adjust height of the side div also to match full available height?

Comment: I just was updated my code so you can see the `#side` in green. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Would be great If i can also use this code in IE7 and 8

Comment: I saw it know, I can't provide container height, container should adjust it's height to main height, and container should be centered only horizontally not vertically

Comment: I just was updated my code so now the `#container` height depend on `#main` height by his content. I hope that's what you are looking for. It's should work on IE8. I have no way to check if it's work on IE7..

Comment: @akapu `display: table` will not work on IE7, and I think you should not worry about that either :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this ---

```css
html, body {height: 100%}
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
#left{
 height: 500px;
 width: 50%;
 float:left;
 background: #363837;
}
#right{
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}
#content{
    position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width: 400px;
    height: 100%
}
#side{
 height: inherit;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 float:left;
 background: blue;
 width: 100px;
    display:none /* set it to block in case you need*/
 }
#main{
 background: white;
 float: right;
 width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="side"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not         only five centuries</p>        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You used a fixed height for left and right div, that's not want i want, I want to adjust left's and right's height to content's height, and I don't want main to be 100% cause it would fill the entire page

Comment: instead of pixels (px) you can use in %(percentage) to make it responsive

Comment: thanks, is there a way not to use 100%, in case i want to add some divs below those divs?

Comment: thanks for your time, however @Mosh Feu already answered my question, thanks once again!